# Trigger same location route

Tags: javascript, routes, backbone.js

Is there a way to trigger same location route in backbone.js, for example when location is `/My/App/#/About` and user clicks again on anchor with the same route in order to refresh the page content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Router.navigate('about', true);
```

That  way you can trigger a route manually.

Answer (score 52):

```
Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);
```

The solution for your specific problem isn't really documented and it seems the suggested best practice is to just call the function that is declared in the route you want to fire :/

Ref: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1214

So far the other answers are correct, but they forgot to mention that if the hash navigated to is the same as the current hash, nothing will fire.

Comment: Seems like it's the only answer that really allows to refresh the same page, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't we use Backbone.history.getFragment() so we don't reach in to history's properties? Seems cleaner to my mind.

Comment: `getFragment()` would certainly be a more appropriate approach with the more modern Backbone. However, I would +1 the comment about running the declared function instead of trying to trick the router to update.

Comment: Alternatively, The more recent `Backbone.Router` class can take an object more than true/false, `Router.navigate(Backbone.history.getFragment(), {trigger:true,replace:true});` this would replace the existing navigation (which it would technically already do, since the destination hash is the same as the current hash)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to do this for more than just the About page, use:

```
route = Backbone.history.fragment;
yourRouter.navigate(route, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the Backbone router looks for changes in the URL fragment you want to load, what worked for me is to navigate to '/' first without trigger, and then subsequently to the URL (fragment) you want to hit with the trigger.  You could probably build this into the default router behavior pretty easily if you wanted.

e.g.

```
App.Routers.appRouter.navigate '/', {trigger: false}
App.Routers.appRouter.navigate myPath, {trigger: true}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Backbone 0.9.2 you pass in an options object and set 'trigger' to 'true'.

```
router.navigate('some/route', { trigger : true });
```

Reference: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate

Comment: This does not work for reloading the current route. navigate returns if the target fragment matches the current fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion @eddywashere, truly awesome. I added a little edit to mine that checks if you're on the last (most currentl) url, and if so, loads that history. Pretty simple, thought it might help someone with the same issue.

```
$("[data-href]").on("click", function(e) {
  var href;
  e.preventDefault();
  href = $(e.currentTarget).data("href");
  if ((_.last(this.history)) === href) {
    return Backbone.history.loadUrl(_.last(this.history));
  } else {
    return this.router.navigate(href, true);
  }
});
```

Comment: care to share this in regular javascript instead of coffeescript?

Answer (score 0):

Another option : you can add a parameter with a random value, so hash will be different for each call, even if you call the same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.navigate(route, {trigger: false}); // Changes URL but it will not trigger...Ex: In place of route -- 'about/1' or 'about' etc

Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment); // Changed route will be triggered here.
```